# Pass Form Vars in Rspec to Update Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm still fairly new to the rspec way. I've read many posts on a redirect_to but cannot seem to get passed this error.  I'm trying to simulate the passing of form variable/value in my rspec test, but getting a routing error.  I'm converting tests to rspec tests on an app that is live and working.

In my employees_micros_controller.rb, I have an update method that expects params[:employees_micro][:id].  My question is How do I simulate this in my rspec test?

Controller:

```
def update
  @em = nil
  # check for id from form
  if params[:employees_micro][:id]
    @em = EmployeesMicro.find_by_id(params[:employees_micro][:id])
  end
  ....
end
```

Rspec Test: note: ### error line ###

```
# update and redirect
describe 'POST #update' do
  it "updates employee_micro and redirect to employee_details" do
    # @emp_micros set in before(each) above
    @emp_micros.home_job = 123
    # update method looks for params[:employees_micro][:id]
    post :update, :employees_micro => { :id => @emp_micros } ### error line ###
    expect(response).to redirect_to("employee_details_employee_path")
  end
end
```

Error:

```
Failure/Error: post :update, :employees_micro => { :id => @emp_micros }
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:employees_micro=>{:id=>"11960"}, :controller=>"employees_micros", :action=>"update"}
```

Is my >> post :update line syntax correct?

I do not understand the routing error.  I'm only trying to simulate passing a form variable to the update method from my test.  If I remove everything after the post/put line, I still get the same error, so it is definitely on that line.

I've also tried using "put" in place of "post" in the test. It nets me the same error.

Thanks for any tips or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update route expects the :id param to be at the top level, so use:

```
post :update, :id => @emp_micros, :employees_micro => { <other attributes to update> }
```

Comment: doing that gives me a "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClassa' error in the controller update method on the params[:employees][:id].  params[:employees][:id] is what is coming from the form, so I need to match that in my rspec test.  The method is not looking for params[:id], but is expecting params[:employees][:id].

Comment: And that is part of the problem. You should be looking up the record with `params[:id]`.

Comment: Agreed!!!  I actually refactored the controller.method to use the id that is in the url for the edit view.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction.  This old app needs a lot of love...